# If I run the command npm install create-react-app my-app, I keep on receiving Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

This Error is stating that the complete run of the command is in my Users/desktop/appdata/npm-cache/_logs/ some strange numbers. here is the issues: and i even try to use --force but all to no avail. pls help:
`PS C:\Users\AHMED\Desktop\youtube-api> npm install --force craete-reacte-app robohash
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/craete-reacte-app - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'craete-reacte-app@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AHMED\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-15T01_24_14_838Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelt the command. It should be `create-react-app` not `craete-reacte-app`

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling, but I tried it is not once that i have tried. and know if I run the command, it is only installing package.lock.json and package.json file and then node_modules only. SO please what is the problem?

Comment: that the complete run of the command is in one of my directory. In users/Ahmed/appdata/local/npm-cache/ some numbers......

Comment: this is the error i get @Christie
C:\Users\AHMED\Desktop>npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\AHMED\Desktop\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/workbox-window failed, reason: Socket timeout
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AHMED\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-17T22_14_45_244Z-debug.log

Comment: Hey @AhmadSalihu it's a network issue. Can you access https://registry.npmjs.org/workbox-window ? The package has failed to access that URL